# Cannot start container in JBoss Fuse 6.0.0

Tags: apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I try to running old JBoss Fuse (6.0.0.redhat-024) server which installed some containers inside

```
JBossFuse:karaf@myapps> fabric:container-list
[id]                         [version]          [alive]          [profiles]                                                                           [provision status]
myapps*                1.1                   true            fmc, fabric, fabric-ensemble-0000-1, jboss-fuse-full         success
     managed1        1.1                  false           default, myprofile                                                               success
     managed2        1.1                  false           default, myprofile                                                               success
```

I tried to start managed1 and managed2 but they seems cannot started and also the log tells nothing.

```
JBossFuse:karaf@myapps> fabric:container-start managed1
JBossFuse:karaf@myapps> fabric:container-start managed2
JBossFuse:karaf@myapps> fabric:container-list
[id]                         [version]          [alive]          [profiles]                                                                           [provision status]
myapps*                1.1                   true            fmc, fabric, fabric-ensemble-0000-1, jboss-fuse-full         success
     managed1        1.1                  false           default, myprofile                                                               success
     managed2        1.1                  false           default, myprofile                                                               success
JBossFuse:karaf@myapps> log:tail
.........
2016-10-20 22:23:51,148 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FabricServiceImpl  | ?  ? | 57 - org.fusesource.fabric.fabric-core - 7.2.0.redhat-024 | Starting container managed1
2016-10-20 22:23:56,221 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FabricServiceImpl  | ?  ? | 57 - org.fusesource.fabric.fabric-core - 7.2.0.redhat-024 | Starting container managed2
```

After read the logs, i found an error during starting fuse:

```
20:17:09,542 | ERROR | guration Watcher | NIOServerCnxnFactory | 53 - org.fusesource.fabric.fabric-linkedin-zookeeper - 7.2.0.redhat-024 | Thread Thread[ActiveMQ Configuration Watcher,5,org.jboss.amq.mq-fabric-6.0.0.redhat-024] died
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.fusesource.mq.fabric.ActiveMQServiceFactory$ConfigThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(ActiveMQServiceFactory.scala:400)[128:org.jboss.amq.mq-fabric:6.0.0.redhat-024]
        at org.fusesource.mq.fabric.ActiveMQServiceFactory$ConfigThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(ActiveMQServiceFactory.scala:399)[128:org.jboss.amq.mq-fabric:6.0.0.redhat-024]
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$2$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(HashMap.scala:102)[56:scala-library:2.9.1]
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$2$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(HashMap.scala:102)[56:scala-library:2.9.1]
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:660)[56:scala-library:2.9.1]
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$$anon$1.foreach(HashTable.scala:157)[56:scala-library:2.9.1]
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:190)[56:scala-library:2.9.1]
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:43)[56:scala-library:2.9.1]
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$2.foreach(HashMap.scala:102)[56:scala-library:2.9.1]
        at org.fusesource.mq.fabric.ActiveMQServiceFactory$ConfigThread.run(ActiveMQServiceFactory.scala:399)[128:org.jboss.amq.mq-fabric:6.0.0.redhat-024]
```

What is happening and how to start the containers?

Comment: You can use Red Hat Customer Portal to get help from Red Hat which supports this product

Comment: I solved the problem with redeploy all again or i recreate the fabric and deploy the profile